# Dropdown.SelectedIndex doesnt have the correct value in the Page_Load event, but has the correct value in the Render event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an aspnet dropdown list in a usercontrol. This usercontrol gets loaded into the webform. There is a submit button on this page too. On postback the selectedItem does NOT show the right value in the Page_load handler but does show the right value in the Pre-render and render handlers. I was under the impression that the viewstate is set before page_load.

Comment: What do you mean by "right value" - is it a user's choice or what? Maybe you could give some source code? I've got impression that you're dealing with some non-standard scenario.

Comment: users selection. problem is it works when i create a new page in a new project. I guess i was just looking at some hints as to what can cause this. Its hard for me to include the entire source code since theres a lot of inheritance going on, but i am sure nothing hooks into the Page / Control events to sabotage viewstate.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably re-data-binding your dropdown list between the pre_render and page_load. Just like the event says, pre_render lets you do stuff before any of the controls on your page have been rendered. So once your page is rendered (before page_load) it's data-binding your dropdown list and erasing your selected value.

The easiest way to get around this is to data-bind your dropdown list in code only when it needs to be bound, like when the page is first loaded and not on post back.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    //Do all of your data binding here
    DataBind();
}
```

Comment: No i am not doing anything, everything is declared in the ascx design page.

Comment: I got the life cycle backwards. Check this out, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479007.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution which is best recommended. **It lies in understandng the Page Life Cycle correctly!!** Postback Controls like Drop Down List restore their posted state (the selected item of a Drop Down List posted). It forgets its selected value because you are rebinding it in Page_Load event, which is after the Drop Down List has been loaded with posted value (because View State is loaded after Page_Init event and before Page_Load event). And in this rebinding in Page_Load event, the Drop Down List forgets its restored selected item. The best solution is to perform the Data Binding in the Page_Init event instead of Page_Load event.

Do something like the below...

Suppose Drop Down List name is lstStates.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lstStates.DataSource = QueryDatabase(); //Just an example.
   lstStates.DataTextField = "StateName";    
   lstStates.DataValueField = "StateCode"; 
   lstStates.DataBind();
}
```

**ASP.NET loads control's View State after Page_Init event and before Page_Load event, so Drop Down List's selectedIndex will not be affected, and you will get desired results magically!!**